# Evaluation in definition

Tags: julia

I am sorry about the title, but I couldn't find a better one.

Let's define

```
function test(n)
    print("test executed")
    return n
end

f(n) = test(n)
```

Every time we call `f` we get

```
f(5)

test executed

5
```

Is there a way to tell julia to evaluate `test` once in the definition of `f`?

I expect that this is probably not going to be possible, in which case I have a slightly different question. If `ar=[1,2,:x,-2,2*:x]` is there any way to define `f(x)` to be the sum of `ar`, i.e. `f(x) = 3*x+1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compile based on type information, you can use [`@generated` functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#Generated-functions-1). But it seems like you want to compile based on the runtime values of the input. In this case, you might want to do memoization. There is a library [Memoize](https://github.com/simonster/Memoize.jl) that provides a macro for memoizing functions.

Comment: `@generated` is what I needed. Thanks!